# jQuery plugin .fn question

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I seem to be having some problems creating a jquery plugin.  I am testing a simple plugin in firebug console and the function is not being defined as I would expect. Here is the code pattern I am using

```
jQuery.fn.test = function () {console.log("runs")}
```

I am trying to call the function with this call which is not working.

```
$.test()
```

But this call does

```
$.fn.test()
```

I don't think this is how it is supposed to work so I think I am doing something wrong, although all the documentation seems to agree that I should be correct.  Any one have any advice?

Thanks,
Cory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$('div').test()`!

Give http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring a read for a good introduction to jQuery plugins.

---

Ok here's some additional info while I'm here. When creating a plugin there three near absolute rules:

- Always use an anonymous method when you define your plugin so you assure you get the jQuery object with `$`.
- Always try to return the jQuery object again (for chaining).
- Always iterate over elements since your selector likely matched more than one element.

So for convention's sake, start off like this:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.test = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      console.log("runs");
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

This will print "runs" for every item matched by your selector (a lot if you use just `div`). Try putting `$(this).css('background-color', 'red');` in and see what happens.

Another good place to look would be various social coding sites ([GitHub](http://github.com), [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org), [Google Code](http://code.google.com), etc.) and search for "jQuery Plugin" to see how others are doing it.

Comment: makes sense that I need to call it on something, that was silly thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of extending jQuery. The one you've chosen allows things like:

```
$("div").test();
```

although the code isn't in the correct form for that. To simply add a static method so you can call:

```
$.test();
```

do this:

```
jQuery.test = function() {
  ...
};
```

See [Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).