# Difference between JQuery plugin and a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When I look at the JQuery plugin code, it almost seems to me that we are creating a function (although we use the `JQuery.fn` syntax) Functionally, what's a difference between a function and a plugin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - difference between $.functionName and $.fn.FunctionName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845981/jquery-difference-between-functionname-and-fn-functionname)

Comment: @redsquare - I disagree that this is a duplicate, he's asking about a function, not a function on the jQuery object, that's a much more narrowly scoped question you linked as a dupe...and it usually has a much narrower and specific purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function is just a normal JavaScript function, for example:

```
function doSomething(param) {
  alert(param);
}
```

A plugin is intended to be run on a set of elements, for example:

```
jQuery.fn.plugin = function(param) {
  return this.attr('something', param);
}
```

This would set the `'something'` attribute on all elements it was called on, like this:

```
$('.selector').plugin('value');
```

If you intend to use the function on a set of elements, like in a jQuery chain, then a plugin may be the answer for you...if you're just calling a function and doing stuff, really having nothing to do with a set of elements, use a plain named function.

Answer (score 3):

Basically a jQuery plugin is a function that is meant to extend jQuery's functionality, and can be applied to selectors more "naturally" than regular functions.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that using $.fn means you can call the function chained onto any jQuery object