# jQuery fn Property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using e.g. Chrome Developer Tools, we can easily inspect JavaScript / jQuery objects. I am trying to understand the following:

```
$.ajax    // defined as 'function ...'
$.fn.ajax // undefined

$.removeClass    // undefined
$.fn.removeClass // defined
```

Since `$.removeClass` is not defined, how come we can invoke e.g. `$('body').removeClass('some-class')`? And, this leads to an error `$('body').fn.removeClass('some-class')`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2845989/174184

Comment: prototypal inheritance. `$.fn` is an alias to the `$.prototype` object.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking about two different types of objects.

`$` is the same as `jQuery` and is a function that has properties on it.  `$.ajax` is one of those properties.

An actual jQuery object as in what `$('body')` creates is actually an object that is an instance of `jQuery.fn.init` not of `jQuery`.

So, that's the first reason that you see different methods on `$` and `$('body')` because they are different types of objects and thus can have different types of methods.

---

To understand further, the methods on `$` (which is a synonym for `jQuery`) are the methods that are added directly to the `jQuery` function itself.  In the jQuery code, this is mostly done with `jQuery.extend()` right on the jQuery object.  `$.ajax` is one of those.

The methods on the jQuery object created by the jQuery function are the methods that are assigned to `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` which due to some trickery by jQuery are the methods assigned to `jQuery.fn`.  As it turns out `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` is set to be the same object as `jQuery.fn` so when anything is assigned to `jQuery.fn`, it automatically goes to `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` and anything on that prototype automatically becomes a method of a `jQuery.fn.init` object which is what is created by the jQuery function such as `jQuery('body')` or `$('body')`.

You can see this in action in the jQuery code.  If you look at the jQuery function, it looks like this (it creates an object of `jQuery.fn.init` and thus will have the methods from `jQuery.fn.init.prototype`:

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

And, then later the `.fn` is like this:

```
// Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

Which is how any method assigned to `jQuery.fn` is also on the `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` and becomes a method on a jQuery object.

Comment: so its basically the same thing...more than explaining it,you have confused it..hope there is an simpler way of knowing it..

Answer (score 2):

When you do something like `var el = $("#content");`, you're dealing with a few different types of objects:

- **Strings.** `"#content"`. 'Nuff said.
- **Functions.** `$` (here, a synonym for `jQuery`) is a function. You're calling it with the string `"#content"`, as we established above.
- **jQuery objects.** The `jQuery` function creates jQuery objects. `el` is one of those objects.

The `jQuery` function and its direct attached properties are mostly things that don't apply to any particular element; they're things you might want to do on their own. Take, for example, `jQuery.ajax`; that doesn't apply to an element, so it was put directly on the `jQuery` function.

Other functionality only makes sense when you've got the context of what elements to apply the operation to. Say, for example, removing a class. If I say `jQuery.removeClass("selected");`, what do I want to remove the class from? You never specified, so you can't do that. Instead, assuming we assigned `el` as above, `el.removeClass("selected");` does indeed make some sense; it removes a class from whatever elements `el` represents (here, the element with an ID of `content`).

Whenever we have one of these function names after the dot, it's a property of something before the dot (either directly or indirectly). In the case of functions like `ajax` where no elements are involved, it's put directly on `$`/`jQuery`. In the case of methods like `removeClass`, it's put on all `jQuery` objects.

Of course, if you ever want to add a new method that can be used on a set of elements like `removeClass`, it would be rather tedious to add that property to every single one, let alone the issue of getting a reference to every jQuery object, past, present, and future! For that reason, `jQuery.fn` is an object that acts as the *prototype* of all jQuery objects. That means that whenever you create a new jQuery object, it will act minimally like the prototype it was based on, `jQuery.fn`. If you add a property to `jQuery.fn`, it will appear on all jQuery objects. In fact, the concept of a prototype is deeply embedded into JavaScript, and modifying `jQuery.fn` will affect *all* jQuery objects, whether they're newly created, created in the past, or created in the future.

Comment: [`$.fn` is actually `$.prototype`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L81) so the *will become properties* bit isn't entirely accurate.

Comment: can i get a bit of detailing..i got completely confused by reading what jfriend00 has written..your answer is clear but needs some detailing

Comment: @VAGABOND: I added some more detail that hopefully should help. I noticed that you edited my answer beforehand to add paragraph breaks and inline code blocks; if you do that again in the future, kindly make sure that what you're wrapping in code blocks actually is code (e.g., you put “object” and “instance” in code blocks, which are technical terms, but aren't code per se).

Comment: @icktoofay:no no no...you got me wrong,i understand the part that you explained.Any ways thx for the answer...

I posted a question yesterday,have a look if you might be interested

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590526/behind-the-scenes-of-jquery-fn-something-and-jquery-something

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to jQuery, but my understanding is that $.fn is a property that contains all methods that can be invoked on jQuery objects.

That's why when you [write a plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), you extend $.fn by adding your own function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function in JavaScript, it is an object:

```
function foo() {...}
foo.bar = 'baz'; //set the `bar` property on `foo`
```

...as well as being a constructor:

```
var f = new foo();
f instanceof foo; //`true`
f.bar; //undefined
```

When you construct an object from a function, the instance will inherit properties from the `prototype` of its constructor function:

```
function Bar() {...}
Bar.prototype = {
    baz: function () {
        console.log('baz');
    }
}
var b = new Bar();
b.baz(); //logs 'baz'
Bar.baz(); //error
```

Additionally, objects in JavaScript are passed by reference*.

```
var fizz,
    buzz;
fizz = {};
buzz = fizz;
buzz.foo = 'bar';
console.log(fizz.foo); //logs 'bar'
```

the jQuery factory function (`jQuery` or `$`) is essentially** defined in the following way:

```
function jQuery(...args...) {
    //the map returned is a jQuery init object
    return new jQuery.init(...args...);
}
//jQuery.init is a function used as a constructor
jQuery.init = function () {...do stuff...};
//jQuery.init.prototype is an object containing the methods that can be called on
//jQuery.init objects
jQuery.init.prototype = {
    addClass: function () {...},
    on: function () {...},
    removeClass: function () {...}
};
//The jQuery.init.prototype object is exposed via jQuery.fn
jQuery.fn = jQuery.init.prototype;
//functions available on the jQuery namespace are added to the jQuery function object.
jQuery.ajax = function () {};
jQuery.extend = function () {};
```

<sub>* *sorta*</sub>
<sub>** gross oversimiplification</sub>