# What is the difference between $ and $.fn?

Tags: jquery

I am too curious to know the difference between `$` and `$.fn`? Can anyone please explain this to me in details? Also what is `$.fn`?

Comment: Duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean?

Comment: did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845981/jquery-difference-between-functionname-and-fn-functionname ? If it doen't respond tell why !

Comment: Before post a question, have a look at the documentation references in the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info).

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer: Yes, I did saw that, but I am looking forward to some explanation with examples/demos which are simple to understand by a layman! Hope you got my point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does jQuery.fn mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$` is a function (specifically, a variable pointing to the `jQuery` function — an alias). `$.fn` is a property on that function, which points to the prototype of the internal `init` function jQuery uses to create instances, as we can see in the jQuery code:

```
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

(That's line 289 of the current un-minified jQuery file, v1.8.3.)

`$.fn` is there so that it's easy to add properties to it. When you create jQuery objects, they have those properties, because of JavaScript's prototypical inheritance. The most common properties to add to it are, of course, functions that do things (jQuery plug-ins).

Answer (score 5):

$.fn is the object containing all $() functions ($ prototype).
So if you define a function on $.fn, every jQuery collection created with $() will have access to your function. jQuery plugins are created using this method, for example:

definition:

`$.fn.myPlugin = function(){...}`

usage:

`$(selector).myPlugin();`

Answer (score 1):

The `fn` property is an alias to the `prototype` property.

The `jQuery` identifier (or `$`) is just a constructor function, and all instances created with it, inherit from the constructor's prototype.

See question: [What does jQuery.fn mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean) for a detailed example