# How to turn function into jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jsFiddlePlayer/vhg7csb7/10/

I am trying to implement the answer in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) as a jQuery plugin and having no luck. The `getParameterByName` function reads the URL's querystring variables and returns the one indicated in the argument. However, my code keeps saying:

> .getParameterByName is not a function

My jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var paramABC = $.getParameterByName('abc');    
    alert(paramABC);
});

(function ($) {
    /* Gets value of querystring variable by name */
    $.fn.getParameterByName = function (name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(('http://www.myexample.com/?abc=1&def=2').search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Note that I've hardcoded a `location` in the above function because jsFiddle doesn't have querystring variables on the URL. The original code for that line was:

```
results = regex.exec(location.search);
```

If this code was working, it would return `1` (because `abc=1` in the querystring) and display it in the `alert()`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there use `$` instead of `$.fn`, as `$.fn` is an alias for the prototype of jQuery and it expects a selector

```
$.getParameterByName = function (name) {
   //
};
```

Note: Define plugin code first then use it.

A good read [What is the difference between $ and $.fn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604040/what-is-the-difference-between-and-fn)

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/zgd8bh2t/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, @Satpal. What's the difference between $ and $.fn?

Comment: @Alex, There is already a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604040/what-is-the-difference-between-and-fn

Comment: Thanks, @Satpal. Why is the alert returning nothing?

Comment: @Alex, `return results === null ? "" ` since location has no query string empty string is returned

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the selector `$()` since you are extending `$.fn`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var paramABC = $().getParameterByName('abc');    
    alert(paramABC);
});

(function ($) {
    /* Gets value of querystring variable by name */
    $.fn.getParameterByName = function (name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(('http://www.myexample.com/?abc=1&def=2').search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```