# Very simple jquery custom function throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.addRemoveButton = function() {
        alert(1);
    };

    $.addRemoveButton();
});
```

And I get the following error message from firebug:

TypeError: $.addRemoveButton is not a function
$.addRemoveButton();

Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: apply this to `DOM` and see..`$(DOM).addRemoveButton();`

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845981/jquery-difference-between-functionname-and-fn-functionname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a selector, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.addRemoveButton = function() {
        alert(1);
    };

    $(document).addRemoveButton();
});
```

[Here is working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yJW78/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply that to any `DOM`.

**Example**

**jQuery Code**

```
$(function()
{
    $.fn.addRemoveButton = function() {
        alert(1);
    };
    $('#letit').addRemoveButton();
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="letit"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

or, you can create it as a jQuery global function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.addRemoveButton = function() { // removed the .fn
        alert(1);
    };

    $.addRemoveButton();
});
```

This binds the function to the jQuery object, where you can then use it like in your original example.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845981/jquery-difference-between-functionname-and-fn-functionname?lq=1) for the difference between `jQuery.fn.method` and `jQuery.method`