# Alternative of .selector property which has been removed in JQuery 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

.selector property has been permanently removed in the JQuery version 3.0 so I'm confused about what should be the replacement of .selector?
In my code I have used the .selector as below:

```
var TaxYearNode = $(EmployerLatestYear).find("TaxYear");
var TaxYear = $(TaxYearNode[j].firstChild.data).selector;
```

This line is showing an error as .selector property not available in JQuery 3.0
Please suggest the alternative way to resolve this problem in JQuery 3.6.3.

```
var EmployerLatestYear = xml.find("Table1"); 

for (var j = 0; j < EmployerLatestYear.find("ID").length; j++) {
 
var TaxYearNode = $(EmployerLatestYear).find("TaxYear"); 

var TaxYear = $(TaxYearNode[j].firstChild.data).selector; 
}
```

Comment: I assume you are missing either a `.` or `#` in `.find("TaxYear")` because right now find is looking for this element `<TaxYear></TaxYear>`

Comment: I am not clear what the second line does, could you post the relevant HTML snippet? In any case your `TaxYearNode` is a jQuery object, to be used for example like `TaxYearNode.val()`

Comment: var EmployerLatestYear = xml.find("Table1");
for (var j = 0; j < EmployerLatestYear.find("ID").length; j++) {
                                    var TaxYearNode = $(EmployerLatestYear).find("TaxYear");
                                    var TaxYear = $(TaxYearNode[j].firstChild.data).selector;
        }

Comment: @PeterThoeny I have added the relevant code for reference.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Please look at the added code for reference.

Comment: @GopalBiswas again you are missing something in `.find("Table1")`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen No, it's perfectly working in the JQuery version jquery-1.10.2

Answer (score 1):

Here are few ways to get around the deprecation:

[Get exact selector in jQuery / alternative to .selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490974/get-exact-selector-in-jquery-alternative-to-selector)

[Get the current jQuery selector string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382028/get-the-current-jquery-selector-string)

For example:

```js
index = document.getElementById('category').value
select = $("#category option[value=#{index}]")[0].innerHTML
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23304487/20394976